# Differentiate between failed UPDATE due to false conditions and failed UPDATE due to unchanged values

Tags: php, mysql

my question is regarding MySQL UPDATE statement it returns `zero` '0' if the update conditions in the `WHERE` clause are not met but also returns `zero` '0' if the values stated in the UPDATE statement are also unchanged and am using `mysqli_affected_rows($conn);` to  check for affected rows is there a way to differentiate between these two failures.

Here is a sample table:

```
ID(auto_increment) | music_name     | price | genre |
556785             | rock star      | $30   | rap   |
896785             | game of thrones| $30   | O.S.T |
116785             | i can dance    | $30   | dance |
```

Here is a sample code:

```
$query="UPDATE `songs` SET `music_name`='$name', `price`='$price' WHERE `genre`=$genre" ;
$result= mysqli_query($conn,$query);

if(mysqli_affected_rows($conn)===0)
{
  $query="INSERT INTO `songs` (`music_name`,`price`,`genre`) VALUES ('$name','$price','$genre')";
  $result=mysqli_query($conn,$query);
}
```

Now this works fine but when ever the same values that already exists in the database table are entered mysqli_affected_rows(); will return `zero` '0' there by causing the INSERT INTO statement to run and we end up with duplicated rows.

How can i make such a query better? without  having to add more queries to select and check the rows first before UPDATE. Also another option maybe using triggers with conditions to delete duplicate rows? but i think there is a better way.

Currently there are no unique columns in the table apart from ID which is on `auto_increment`

Comment: Does `music_name` column is unique?

Comment: What is the actual problem, that you are not aware upfront whether you will have to insert a new record or update an existing one? Then you should go check out [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

Comment: no there are no unique columns in my case, if there were unique columns the insert statement will not run and i will have nothing to worry about

Comment: apart from the ID column which is auto_increment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all , if the values are the same, MySQL will not update the row  so the affected row count will be 0.

**Solution for this issue :**

```
$query="SELECT count(*) as cnt FROM `songs` WHERE `music_name`='$name', `price`='$price' AND `genre`=$genre" ;
/****get count from the query******/
if(count > 0 ) {
//update the table row
}
else{
//insert the table row
}
```

Comment: yes this will work but am trying to cut down on the number of queries i have to run if there are no other solutions then i will accept your answer.

Comment: found a more suitable solution and updated your answer thanks for pointing me in the right direction.